# Weighting data by removing some variables from data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the weights for each variable except the second variable

```
    variables      values      w
1:      Var1  0.02480052 40.3217290
2:      Var3  0.02657701 37.6264988
3:      Var4 -0.37417694  2.6725324
4:      Var5  1.30037139  0.7690111
5:      Var6  0.73508732  1.3603826
6:      Var7  0.02313702 43.2207787
7:      Var8  0.64506139  1.5502400
8:      Var9  0.10391410  9.6233330
9:     Var10  0.34537472  2.8954059
```

I have to scale the corresponding variables by their weight `w`values( ignoring the second variable because it has no weight).I have used the following command `body.w.cp=scale(body,center=F,scale=w)` but the confusion is that some weights are shown as "NA" :

```
 [1]   7.8438793          NA  10.2326453   0.5153231   0.9211145  15.2608703
 [7] 117.5024079   0.3937697   2.2007466   1.7361693
```

so how could i weight the corresponding variables and get the other variables same which do not have a weight value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base R's `scale()` function accepts three parameters: `x`, `center` and `scale`.

Particularly, `scale` has to be either a logical value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of columns of x. ). If **scale is a numeric vector with length equal to the number of columns of x, then each column of x is divided by the corresponding value from scale**.

In your particular case, when you run `scale(body, scale=w)`, your `w` has to be a named variable in your environment. If it is the vector that you showed above, then each column of `body` is divided by the corresponding value from scale, and anything divided by a missing value (`NA`) will also be `NA`. For example:

```
4/as.numeric(NA)
```

will return `NA`.

So instead of *ignoring the second variable because it has no weight* like you stated, you may just want to have the second variable be 1 instead of "NA". The resulting vector should make sense then.